# Making Routes in Laravel from URL

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes

If our URL is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/student/submit-details/1234` then its Route will be:

```
Route::get('student/submit-details/{id}',
'studentController@submitDetails')->name('submitDetails');
```

What will be the route if the URL is following?

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/student/submit-details?code=1234
```

I'm using the following Route, but it is not picking it and not working. Does anyone know what will be its Route? I went through the documentation and found no help there.

```
Route::get('student/submit-details?code={id}', 'MyController@submitDetails');
```

Comment: Try to accept any answer that helped you

Answer (score 2):

Your route should be look like as:

```
Route::get('student/submit-details', 'studentController@submitBankDetails')->name('submitBankDetails');
```

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/student/submit-details?code=1234
```

in above URL string after the question mark is query parameter and get the value of the query parameter in the controller you should use $_GET:

```
$_GET['code']
```

Comment: Could you mark as an answer then, please? Then I'm helped too :D

Answer (score 1):

The placeholder parameters for routes are only specified for Route parameters but rather for query parameters. The `Route` should be only

```
Route::get('student/submit-details', 'MyController@submitDetails');
```

You can access the value in the controller via `Request` instance

```
public function submitDetails(Request $request) {
   dd($request->code);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/student/submit-details?code=1234`

```
Route::get('student/submit-details', 'studentController@submitBankDetails')->name('submitBankDetails');
```

Comment: if its help for you then please mark as verified this answer thank you @Knowledge Seeker

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `get method`

```
Route::get('student/submit-details', 'studentController@submitBankDetails')->name('submitBankDetails');
```

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel if you want to pass data with `GET` method :

```
Route::get('student/submit-details', 'studentController@submitBankDetails')->name('submitBankDetails');
```

It will give you output like this :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/student/submit-details?code=1234
```

If you have multiple *parameter*, it will like :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/student/submit-details?code=1234&code2=5678
```

You can access the *parameter* from controller like this :

```
public function edit(Request $request){
   $code = $request->input('code');
   dd($code); // 1234
}
```

Take a look at the [**$_GET**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) and [**$_REQUEST**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) superglobals.

Answer (score 0):

If you want route

```php
http://127.0.0.1:8000/student/submit-details?code=1234
```

Route route will be

```php
Route::get('student/submit-details', 'studentController@submitBankDetails')->name('submitBankDetails');
```

And usage

```php
route('submitBankDetails', ['code' => 1234])
```